# Problem when removing a row from a table in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database like this:

```
public static final String TABLE = "NOTE_TABLE";
public static final String ID = "COLUMN_ID";
public static final String CHARS = "COLUMN_CHARS";
public static final String DATE = "COLUMN_DATE";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTableStatemnet = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE +
            " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + CHARS + " TEXT," + DATE + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTableStatemnet);
}
```

I defined a method to remove a row:

```
public void removeOne(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE, "COLUMN_CHARS=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    db.close();
}
```

and call it from an `onClickListener()`

```
public void remove(View view) {
    dataBase = new DataBase(MainActivity.this);
    // 1 here is the id of the row i want to delete
    dataBase.removeOne(1);
}
```

but when I check the Database inspector no row is removed.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void removeOne(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_ID=?", new Int[] { id });
    db.close();
}
```

or

```
public void removeOne(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE, "COLUMN_ID=?", new Int[] { id });
    db.close();
}
```

because you are passing id (Int) and you are trying to delete with COLUMN_CHARS (String)

hope it work